# Gravitational field of a moving object

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, kinematics, acceleration, field-theory

Here's a simple scenario:
Let's say, that there are 2 stationary planetoids of equal mass on the Earth's orbital motion path, placed at equal distances from Earth just like on the image below:

### [image: scenario]

Will both planetoids start to accelerate towards Earth at the same rate or will the rate of acceleration differ for each of them? To simplify it, let's say that Earth motion path is linear.

Comment: Related, but not really the same: [What is a Lagrange Point?](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/754/what-is-a-lagrange-point/)

Comment: I would say, that Lagrange points are created due to gravitational interactions between Earth and Sun, so it's rather not directly related to Earth's orbital motion. What I'm interested in, is the influence of source's motion on the geometry of it's gravitational field, as it is observed in a stationary frame.

Comment: Taged as [tag:special-relativity] but arguably ought to be [tag:general-relativity] as it deals with gravity.  However in terms of Earth-sized bodies there is really little point in considering relativity at all as the effects are very, very small in this case.

Comment: Yeah, it's conneted partially with SRT and partially with GRT. I've used Earth just as an example, to demonstrate the problem but there is no problem with using a more massive body, as the moving source of a gravitational field. What I'm interested in, is the influence of relative motion of a source on the geometry/distribution of it's gravitational field. I've searched the internet for anything regarding this probem, but there's literally nothing...

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm interested in, is the influence of source's motion on the geometry of it's gravitational field, as it is observed in a stationary frame.

If Earth is considered the object the planetoids are stationary relative to at the start (your question is somewhat amniguous), then the natural "stationary frame" would be Earth which would, in that frame of reference, have no motion at all.   From then on the two planetoids will simply be attracted towards Earth (and each other) equally (but in opposite directions) and their motion would be symmetric about Earth if their initial motion was stationary relative to Earth.

If the Earth is considered to be moving towards one body and away from the other, the natural stationary reference frame is the mid point between the two planetoids at the start (where Earth is at the start).

> Will both planetoids start to accelerate towards Earth at the same rate or will the rate of acceleration differ for each of them?

In this case relativistic effects are completely negligible and it's simply a Newtonian gravitational problem with the two bodies in effect starting out with different velocities relative to Earth and the result is qualitatively simple : the body starting out approaching Earth hits Earth sooner that the other body which is (from Earth's point of view) moving away from it at the start.  Earth's motion relative to the "stationary frame" as defined in this case would be slightly perturbed (from simple linear motion at a constant velocity) by what would be different forces from the two bodies (as they would occupy different positions at different time and hence the gravitational forces between them and Earth would be different).

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly, what I'm interested in. If we'll stick to the Earth example, we can then use the frame of Sun, as a stationary one (excluding the rotational motion). However I have here 2 issuess: 1. you said, that "it's simply a Newtonian gravitational problem with the two bodies in effect starting out with different velocities relative to Earth" - if we exclude the gravity, then in the very beginning (t=0) both planetoids have the same velocity but with opposite directions of their motion  in relation to Earth.

Comment: 2 You said " the body starting out approaching Earth hits Earth sooner that the other body which is (from Earth's point of view) moving away from it at the start" - problem is, that at some distance from the source object, the test object placed "behind" the source (moving away from the source) will be accelerating faster, than the source object will be moving away from it, so from the rest frame of source it will appear that both objects are accelerating towards it at different rates (with the object "in front" accelerating faster, than the one "behind" it).

Comment: And one more question: how the initial velocity of a massive object is incorporated in the Newton's formula for gravity: GM/r^2 ?

Comment: @BartłomiejStaszewski Either you're using the Sun (orbital motion is important) or it's linear motion with no Sun.  Those are two completely different problems.

Comment: I'm just trying to simplify the problem as much as I can - so maybe the best solution, is to reduce the scenario to linear motion of the source object and some undefined stationary bystander.

Comment: @BartłomiejStaszewski (2) I am not sure what your issue is here.  And (3) you need to use the standard equations of motion using e.g. Newtonian mechanics that link force (or potential) and position and velocity.  Initial values are simply that - initial values you "fix" the general solution to produce a specific solution for a given system.

Comment: *some undefined stationary bystander*  You conceptual issue is that you **must** define the reference frame yourself.  You can transform to another frame but there is no such thing as an "undefined stationary bystander".  I think you are confusing the use of a "distant observer" in general relativity with the choice of coordinate system in a problem.  A distant observer does not define a coordinate system.

Comment: As for (2): My issue is with the direction of relative motion for the object located "behind" the source. Dependind on the distance from the source, this test object will be a) initially moving away from it, then decelerate to 0 and start to accelerate towards it b) accelerate towards the source from the beginning. In the case of situation b) in the rest frame of the source it won't be possible to tell, that test object was initially moving away from it, so how it would be possible to explain different rates of acceleration for both test objects (distance and mass is the same for both)

Comment: @BartłomiejStaszewski Rates of acceleration are a result of net forces acting on the bodies.  The forces depend only on distance.  I suspect you are overthinking this and need to sit put it aside for a while and return to it with a clean sheet.

Comment: As for (3): I don't know any equation, which would combine the standard equations of motion in Newtonian mechanics with his equation for acceleration due to gravity: G* (m1*m2)/r^2. - it includes ony the masses of interacting objects and the distance between them. We would probably need to include the initial momentum of interacting bodies, but there's no such thing in the standard formula...

Comment: @ StephenG So "You can transform to another frame but there is no such thing as an "undefined stationary bystander". So to be clear, I mean a frame, where both test objects are stationary at t=0, while the source object is moving at a given velocity V in relation to those test objects.

Comment: @ StepheG "Rates of acceleration are a result of net forces acting on the bodies. The forces depend only on distance." - well, in your answer you said: "the body starting out approaching Earth hits Earth sooner that the other body which is (from Earth's point of view) moving away from it at the start" - so, it would seem, that the initial velocity and direction of motion in relation to the source have also to play a crucial role. TBC

Comment: ...If a test body is initially moving away from the source, then you need to apply more work, to stop it and then make it to accelerate in opposite direction, than it would be needed only to accelerate a stationary body towards the source.

Comment: I agree, that the force working on a test object depends here only on the distance to the source and in this case at t=0 is equal for both test objects, but in order, to solve this scenario, we would have probably to calculate, how  this force relates to the initial momenum or kinetic energy of test objects. It might seem, that the entire problem is quite easy to solve, but it is in fact quite tricky...

Comment: I do think you're overthinking this. The (Newtonian) equations of motion are $x(t) = x_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2}a(t) t^2$. $v_0$ is the initial velocity of whichever object (Planetoid or Earth) that you pick. This is frame dependent, of course: in the "sun reference frame" it is 0 for both planetoids, non-zero for Earth, in the "Earth reference frame" it is $+v$ for one planetoid and $-v$ for the other. $a(t)$ is the acceleration due to gravity, which depends on distance and hence on time. Relativistic effects will be negligible. This is all much easier to calculate in the Earth-stationary frame